What is the movie all about Illusions where a group work together using whole US city
There is a group of people performing the illusions and they are constantly on the move to avoid capture by the police. The final grand illusion uses a whole city (New York? Las Vegas?)

Now You See Me.
Now You See Me is a 2013 American caper thriller film directed by Louis Leterrier. The film stars Jesse Eisenberg, Mark Ruffalo, Woody Harrelson, Mélanie Laurent, Isla Fisher, Dave Franco, Common, Michael Caine and Morgan Freeman.
